# Doctrine DQL with SELECT, GROUP BY, COUNT Semantical Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'd like to perform query like:
`` SELECT o.lang, COUNT(o.id) FROM `order` o GROUP BY o.lang; ``.
I try:

```
$entityManager->getRepository(Order::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->select(["o.baseLang", "COUNT(o.id)"])
    ->groupBy("o.baseLang")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

, but I get `Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression`.
How do I do this?

Comment: PathExpression means something with your fields. I guess something with o.baseLang. if baseLang is a foreign key probably, most likely you need to add join or call it with identity

Answer (score 0):

You put:

```
$entityManager->getRepository(Order::class)
->createQueryBuilder('o')
->select(["IDENTITY(o.baseLang)", "COUNT(o.id)"])
->groupBy("o.baseLang")
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```